# Can't connect to Sql Server 2008 using VS 2015 community

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2015

help me guys. why is it i can't add a connection to sql server 2008. im using visual studio 2015 community. it say's "This server version is not supported. You must have Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or later." but im using sql server 2008 and i don't understand why. can someone help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Where and how are you trying to add that connection? What are the settings you are using?

Comment: Data source: Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)

Comment: and still doesn't connect

Comment: Do you have SSMS installed? Can you connect from that?